# move button along with picturebox vb/c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, panel, picturebox

I am working on a mapped DVR/cctv UI. 
I made it myself, so I did not use google's API. I just cut off big part of the map where I need it.

so, if I do have a really big map, then it won't fit in my pc's resolution, I haven't found a code to move the picture inside the pictureBox, but what I did is to move the pictureBox inside a panel. then it looked like a map, with boundaries. :)

now, I want to be able to save/attach this button to the picture.. so whenever and wherever I move the pictureBox, button gets along with it. even if goes outside the form, but when I drag it back, it appears to where it was let's say, **attached** just imagine the button like googlemap's marker. that's what I wanted to happen.

its like I am building my own **offline google map**..

[image]

if you have queries, feel free to ask. TIA

Comment: You will have to calculate the position of the button according to the map position and set them on map event

Comment: its not actually a map, its only a **picture** of the map. also, I don't know how to do that, I learn via understanding the code. :)

Comment: The button has 2 properties, `Location.X and Location.Y` which you can manipulate to move the button programmatically on execution.

Comment: do I really need to calculate its location if it needs to be referenced to the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add your button as a child of your picturebox:

```
button1.Parent = pictureBox1;
//or
pictureBox1.Controls.Add(button1);
```

Then you can use the `Location` property of your button to set it accordingly, that location is relative to your pictureBox, not your form.

If you want to keep the *design location* of your button, you can try this code:

```
Point loc = pictureBox1.PointToClient(button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty));
button1.Parent = pictureBox1;
button1.Location = loc;
```

Comment: let me try, I think, if you first put/add your button on top of the picture box, its location is relative to it. I have been thinking of how much was added to the location of my picture then I need to add the same thing to the button, but I think that it will have discrepancies, before that I will try this.

Comment: @AdorableVB no problem, just try it, if there is any other trouble around that approach, just ask it here as a comment, I'll try to help.

Comment: it seems to adopt the picturebox' location, but one thing, it saves the initial position of the form, on design view not the picture. its not the one that I expected, but it does what it needs to do (draggable with the picture) and I think that I will have future problems if I use this. any other solutions?

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236430/move-winform-in-relation-to-a-button-from-another-form-vb-c