# move winform in relation to a button from another form vb/c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I want you to check on [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235226/drag-button-along-with-picturebox-vb-c) first..

that's what I am working on, problem solved on the button, and now, I need to make a WinForm follow the button wherever and whenever I drag the map/picture. it is something like this, infowindows on google's API. first picture, I made it on html.

[image]

and this one.. this is what I am working on now, on winForms, I can't drag form2 with the picture..
[image]

this is my current code..

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim loc As Point = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty))
    Button1.Parent = PictureBox1
    Button1.Location = loc

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub pictureBox1_LocationChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim p As Point = button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
    p.Offset(5, 10)
    Form2.Location = p
    Form2.Owner = Me
End Sub
```

as you can see, that infowindow, I want that to be a  form in my winForms. Is it possible that its location can be relative/parent to the button just like from the link above. thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, do you mean you want your `infowindow` to move together with your `button` or your `pictureBox`?

Comment: just like what you did, first was the button to move with the picture, right? now, I want it to move exactly how the button does, but the catch is, the winForm must be in relative to the button, like the picture above. as a result, I move the pic, button moves along, winForm moves along too.

Comment: What is the type of `infoWindow`? A `Form`? or a `ToolStripControlHost`? ...

Comment: I don't really know what type of form that is likely to be used, but I need it to be able to handle/contain an **activeX** control(cctv camera) + some buttons perhaps. that's the important thing, then you can choose what's better for use.

Comment: @KingKing I have yet another question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256176/how-to-use-extract-identity-of-a-control-inside-an-activex-control-gmaps-net-vb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try handling the `LocationChanged` of your picturebox like this:

```
//LocationChanged event handler for your pictureBox1
private void pictureBox1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  //Get the location of button1 in screen coordinates
  Point p = button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
  //Offset it to what you want
  p.Offset(5,10);
  //set the location for your infoWindow form
  infoWindow.Location = p;
}
```

Note that I use `infoWindow` as a form, I think it's usable in your case, set the `FormBorderStyle` to `None` and add some custom close button ... (You can search for more on this, there are tons of examples). In case you don't know how to register the `LocationChanged` event handler, here it is:

```
pictureBox1.LocationChanged += pictureBox1_LocationChanged;
```

Also note that your `infoWindow` form must have your main form as its owner:

```
infoWindow.Owner = yourMainForm;
//or this if the code is placed inside mainForm class
infoWindow.Owner = this;
```

**Update**:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim loc As Point = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty))
  Button1.Parent = PictureBox1
  Button1.Location = loc
  Form2.Owner = Me
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub pictureBox1_LocationChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.LocationChanged

  Dim p As Point = button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
  p.Offset(-Form2.Width/2, -Form2.Height-10)
  Form2.Location = p

End Sub
```

Comment: I have added that code, but not the locationChanged thingy.. also, I have updated my question. that's not working for me..

Comment: @AdorableVB do you mean the code I posted works but the Location of your `infoWindow` is not what you want (as shown in the updated pic)?

Comment: nope, code doesn't work either, I just put the form on top, to make it look like what I wanted for it to appear.

Comment: @AdorableVB I see you actual code now, in fact it does not register `pictureBox1.LocationChanged` event handler. wait for a moment while I update the code in VB.NET for you.

Comment: works now! but only after I dragged the picture, can I put its code to 'button1_Click'?
EDIT: sorry wasn't thinking. I cannot right? by then it cannot be dragged. anyway, thanks!

Comment: Good, also I'd think about having single control for both info window and button

Comment: @lazyberezovsky yes, it's OK, however looks like the OP's happy about his approach :)